# Apppool keeps stopping (login Failed for user 'NT Authority\anonymous logon' using service account)

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I have seen that many other people are having the same issue as me, but every problem is a little different, as is mine.

I created a service account that will run the web app.  This account is in the database and has the correct permissions.

I think the problem might be in my connection string. I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to the correct syntax, that's why I believe that is where the problem is.

```
<add name="1AWebApp_Prod" connectionString="server=serverName;Initial Catalog=databaseName; Integrated Security=true; uid=nanw\svc_fawebprod_ria" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

---

**Update:**

I removed the user name and am now getting a HTTP error 500.3 - service unavailable
i went in to the apppool and noticed that everytime I access the site from the browser it stops the apppool

I set *Rapid-Fail Protection: Enable* to *False*, this has not fixed the issue

When I run `aspnet_regiis -ga nanw\svc_fawebprod_ria` I get the error *"the user does not exist*"

---

**Update 2:**

Created a mirrored version of the service account, [Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649309.aspx)
Ran 'aspnet_regiis -ga svc_fawebprod_ria', worked
The app pool is no running and not stopping every second

Now I'm getting "*Login failed. the login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be usd with Windows authentication*"

Comment: Did you remove the uid completely? Try opening the web.config in visual studio - it may show you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the app and the db are not joined to the same domain this isn't possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to supply a username when using integrated security (it uses the current logged in user or the account running the service in question).

What account is the app pool that the web app is running under?  I guess that it has not been set.

Comment: the account in the appPool has been set and is the same account that is used in the db.  ill remove the username